# Disable a button in MFC HTML dialog

Tags: mfc

I have a problem within MFC html dialog.

```
<BUTTON STYLE="WIDTH:56px; position: absolute; top: 151px; left: 11px;" ID="ButtonOK">BtnOK</BUTTON>
```

.....

```
DHTML_EVENT_ONCLICK(_T("ButtonOK"), OnButton1)
```

.....

```
HRESULT CAbsolute_LolkrDlg::OnButton1(IHTMLElement* pElement){
    //Disable This Button 
}
```

I have a button in my dialog, When I press this button, I want to disable it,
I have searched in Google, but I cannot find out how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javaScript for this purpose, just try this example code:

JavaScript

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function ok()
{
    document.getElementById("ButtonOK").disabled = true;
    return true;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

HTML

```
<BUTTON style="width:100" id="ButtonOK" onclick="ok()">Ok</BUTTON>
```

By using this method you are able disable your button.
On single click it will call both
 `ok()` and

```
HRESULT CAbsolute_LolkrDlg::OnButton1(IHTMLElement* pElement){
    //Do anything else you want to do 
}
```

Comment: thank for reply, I have a question.  If I have a condition in the last function(OnButton1), how can i do it?

Comment: if(condition){disable} such like this

Comment: if you can check that condition in html then you can write like you have written in comment.

Comment: Otherwise if condition is in mfc then search for function in google "how to call javascript in mfc" then you can call javascript function using mfc also.

Comment: [Check this link](http://pastebin.com/mSMeeBpr) how you can call javascript function using mfc/vc++.